# Pass sidedrawer data to homepage

Tags: nativescript

I have used the SideDrawer example and have a series of dropdown's on my SideDrawer. After the last selection I need to display details on the underlying page, in this case the homepage. How do I update the underlying page as a result of my selections.

Don't know where to start.

```
    exports.installationIndexChanged = function (args){
    const drawerComponent = args.object;
    const sideDrawer = app.getRootView();
    var context = sideDrawer.bindingContext;
    var installation = drawerComponent.items[args.newIndex];
    console.log(installation);
    var installDD = drawerComponent.getViewById("installation");
    var selectedInstall = installDD.selectedIndex;
    appSettings.setNumber("id",(installDD.get("items").getValue(selectedInstall)));
}
```

the last line in the code above gets the ID of the record I need to display. I'm not sure if I can address the underlying page at this point, or need to know when the sidedrawer closes, display the record then. My preference would be to keep the sidedrawer open and display the record on the homepage first. The user can then close the sidedrawer to view the complete record.

Comment: Dunno how much help this will be -- but i've been using NativeScript + Vue; so whenever I needed to capture/read data from different pages, I used a Vuex store.

Comment: `sideDrawer.maincontent` should return the root element of main content, you may probably have a frame there, from frame you can get the `currentPage`.

Comment: OK thanks for the hint, but this is very new to me. Can you show some simple code implementing this principle.

Comment: For example if I have a label on the home page, how to I set the labels text to the selected ID from the sidedrawer drop-down